# Resizing RootViewController in SplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Is it possible to resize the RootViewController in SplitViewController? I am looking for an effect like the image below. On the left hand side, the orange gradient bar will be the RootViewController. If it's not possible, what are my alternatives? Should I just make the entire screen a large ViewController with and add a subview on the left end?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm curious why you would even bother with split view in this case? What are you gaining by using a split view? It seems like you would be better off just using a normal VC with a subview.

Comment: You think so? The reason why i want a splitview is because the left bar will ALWAYS be there. So, rather than putting the left bar in EVERY VC, i thought it would be easier. Also, there's a tab bar there. I can't put a view and a view controller inside a viewcontroller (hope that makes sense lol). Let me know what you think, it be great there was an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) or [APSplitViewController](https://github.com/SlavaBushtruk/APSplitViewController).

Comment: Thanks. MGSplitViewController looks awesome!

Comment: It is great. Not only does it have a lot of addiitonal functionality, but it fixes the many, many bugs in UISplitViewController.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `UISplitViewController` is so problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add the persistent view to the applications rootview or window.